# Subqueries for php

Tags: php, mysql

sorry if this might be a duplicate question but im desperatly needs help for project submission.

I have a database carpark where i have 2 table within which is carpark_availability and history.

From my code, im able to get a field "development" from table carpark_availability.
I would like to ask on how to structure my queries if i want to select * from c where my h.development = c.development.

As shown below is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','carpark_project');
    $dev = $_SESSION["development"]; 
    echo "Development: ";
    echo $dev;



    $sql = "select * from carpark_availability where 
            carpark_availability.Development IN (select history.development 
            from history where
            history.Development = '$dev' )";
   //$sql = "select * from carpark_availability where development = '$dev'";
   //$sql = "select * from carpark_availability where (select Development
   //from history where Development= '$dev'";

   $result = $con->query($sql);


   while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc())
   { 

        echo "Development: ";
        echo $row["Development"]. "</br>";
        echo $row["Area"]."</br>";
        echo $row["weekday1"]."</br>";
    } 

 ?>
```

Comment: Look at/count the brackets in your SQL statement

Comment: More information about mysql joins can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Hi, i just saw that i lack of 1 bracket. But it still doesnt solve the problem. it gave me this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean"

Comment: Update the question with the new code. Use mysqli error reporting to see what the issue is.

Comment: hi @chris85, thank you for your advice. I've tried the error reporting but there was no output of error messages

Comment: Can you show how you used the error reporting? You used http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your `carpark_availability` and `history` tables structure.

Comment: Your code may be vulnerable to SQL injection, since you are using the session data without escaping it before.

Answer (score 1):

A join is much easier on the eye than a subquery.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM carpark_availability c
INNER JOIN history
USING (development)
GROUP BY development;
```

I'm guessing you are getting an error because your query is returning no results so `$result` is set to boolean `false`. You have nothing in your code to check for that so you are trying to call `fetch_assoc()` on it